# Merge Sort, sorting dates properly but not integer values

Tags: javascript, sorting, mergesort

I am doing a coding challenge trying to learn merge sort and I have gotten my merge sort to handle dates properly but not an integer value. Currently it seems to outputting data at random.

EDIT: There are over a dozen different posts like the sample data listed. I am unable to sort each of those objects based on their votes from high to low

**My Merge Sort Function:**

```
function sortBy(array, key, descending = false) {
  const length = array.length;
  if (length === 1) {
    return array;
  } else if (length === 2) {
    const aValue = array[0][key];
    const bValue = array[1][key];
    if (bValue > aValue) {
      return array;
    }
    return [
      array[0],
      array[1],
    ];
  }

  const mid = Math.floor(length / 2);
  const firstHalf = array.slice(0, mid);
  const secondHalf = array.slice(mid, length);

  const arrayOne = sortBy(firstHalf, key);
  const arrayTwo = sortBy(secondHalf, key);

  const merged = [];
  while (arrayOne.length || arrayTwo.length) {
    if (!arrayOne.length) {
      merged.push(arrayTwo.shift());
      continue;
    }

    if (!arrayTwo.length) {
      merged.push(arrayOne.shift());
      continue;
    }

    const valueOne = arrayOne[0][key];
    const valueTwo = arrayTwo[0][key];
    if (valueOne <= valueTwo) {
      merged.push(arrayOne.shift());
    } else if (valueTwo < valueOne) {
      merged.push(arrayTwo.shift());
    }
  }

  return descending ? merged.reverse() : merged;
}
```

**Sample Data**

```
    [{
    created: '2016-03-07T05:24:40.340Z',
    details: 'Right now we only support single backticks. Would be nice to do triple as well... Consider supporting more or all of markdown but I\'m not sure that\'s the right direction.',
    title: 'Support triple backtick codeblocks',
    votes: 17,
  },]
```

Comment: Ok...in your sample data there is only one number 17, where's the rest? Also, after you manage to provide data that we can actually work with, please post what you were actually expecting. Just looking at the OP code implies that sorting isn't what your after so explain exactly the pattern you are trying to do as well.

Comment: Edited post. Unable to sort my sample data votes from high to low

Comment: Is it just one object inside one array and many more like that? Or is it more saner like multiple objects inside an array?

Comment: Multiple objects in an array

Comment: Ok, I think I [got it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72835834/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things I see just reading through the code:

1. need to access different elements of the array in the last return statement

```
const length = array.length;
  if (length === 1) {
    return array;
  } else if (length === 2) {
    const aValue = array[0][key];
    const bValue = array[1][key];
    if (bValue > aValue) {
      return array;
    }
    return [
      array[0], // needs to be array[1]
      array[1], // needs to be array[0]
    ];
  }
```

2. You need to be passing the third argument down everytime you recurse the function

   `const arrayOne = sortBy(firstHalf, key, descending);`

   `const arrayTwo = sortBy(secondHalf, key, descending);`

Comment: Let me know if this helps get you closer. If it does, please edit your question and I can help you out some more if you need it.

Comment: Anthony B, thank you for seeing that logic error in the code you pasted. I am actually really confused by it and its not entirely making sense to me why I had to swap those two indices

Comment: When you are doing a merge sort, you are always trying to get to a point where either you just return the array (length = 1) or you can do a comparison to sort the values (length = 2).
So when you have an array [A,B] A is index [0], B is index [1], you compare:
if B.votes > A.votes, then swap the order by having the array be [B,A].

Comment: I did find a bug with your code in point 3. arrayTwo[1][key] gives an error. "Cannot read property 'votes' of undefined

Comment: Absolutely right. Point number 3 is not correct. After thinking about it more, you have your two arrays and you're looking at the first value in each array with each loop. I will edit my response.

Comment: I will accept the answer after the edit.